# Get max value of multiple group by in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with this cols and values:

```text
|employee|department|salary|
+--------+----------+------+
|   James|     Sales| 90000|
| Michael|     Sales| 86000|
|  Robert|     Sales| 81000|
|   Maria|   Finance| 90000|
|   Raman|   Finance| 99000|
|   Scott|   Finance| 83000|
|    Jeff| Marketing| 80000|
|   Kumar| Marketing| 91000|
|   Sarah| Marketing| 95000|
```

I want to have a dataframe with the `employee` with the highest `salary` for each `department`.

So my result will be :

```text
|employee|department|highest salary|
+--------+----------+---------------+
|   James|     Sales|         90000|
|   Raman|   Finance|         99000|
|   Sarah| Marketing|         95000|
```

I already tried multiple things with `groupby` but I don't know what to do.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group by and `max` on struct column to get the highest `salary` by `department` with the associated `employee` like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.groupBy("department") \
    .agg(F.max(F.struct("salary", "employee")).alias("max")) \
    .selectExpr("max.employee", "department", "max.salary as highest_salary")

result.show()
#+--------+----------+--------------+
#|employee|department|highest_salary|
#+--------+----------+--------------+
#|   Raman|   Finance|         99000|
#|   Sarah| Marketing|         95000|
#|   James|     Sales|         90000|
#+--------+----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytic functions `rank` or `row_number`.

```
df = df.withColumn('rank', F.expr('rank() over (partition by department order by salary desc)')) \
    .filter('rank=1').drop('rank')
df.show(truncate=False)
```